# this.props.xxxx is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

```js
class UserForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { user } = props;
  }
  _cancelForm() {
    this.props.onCancel();
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
    <button onClick={this._cancelForm.bind(this)}> Cancel </button>
    );
  }
}

class UserCreate extends React.Component {
  _navigateToLogin() {
    console.log("hi")
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
    <div>
      <UserForm onCancel={this._navigateToLogin.bind(this)}/>
     </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( 
  <UserCreate/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

```
import React from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import UserForm from './UserForm'
import UsersService from '../services/UsersService'

 class UserCreate extends React.Component{
    _navigateToLogin() {
      this.props.history.push('/homepage');
    }

    async _saveUser(user) {
      await UsersService.createUser(user);
      this._navigateToLogin();
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
              <UserForm
                onCancel={this._navigateToLogin.bind(this)}
                onSubmit={this._saveUser.bind(this)} 
              />
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default withRouter(UserCreate)
```

---

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  Button
} from '@material-ui/core'


export default class UserForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const { user } = props;

    this.state = {
       ...
    }


  _handleFormSubmit() {
    const user = {
      ...
    };
    this.props.onSubmit(user);
  }

  _cancelForm() {
    this.props.onCancel();
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div style={{ width: '100%', height: 'auto', position: 'fixed', minWidth: '100%', minHeight: '100%', backgroundColor: '#50617C' }}>
              <Button size="small" onClick={ this._cancelForm.bind(this) }>Back</Button>
              <Button size="small" onClick={ this._handleFormSubmit.bind(this) }>Create</Button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The error is present when I click the "Back" button on CreateAccountForm, it returns an error that says that the onCancel function is not a function. I'm sending it on the UserCreate by binding and I'm calling it on the function _cancelForm(). I was thinking that the error is that I'm missing something in the constructor according to some react documentation, I used before this method and it worked, right now I don't know what's happening.

Comment: Is `import UserForm from './UserForm'` the same component as from `CreateAccountForm`? Just checking you have the correct code snippets copied.

Comment: Yes, sorry, let me change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted does not demonstrate the error, below is your code and it works just fine.

```js
class UserForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  _cancelForm() {
    this.props.onCancel();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this._cancelForm.bind(this)}>
        cancel
      </button>
    );
  }
}
class UserCreate extends React.Component {
  _navigateToLogin() {
    console.log('in navigate login');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <UserForm
          onCancel={this._navigateToLogin.bind(this)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <UserCreate />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Can you provide a minimal [snippet](https://gist.github.com/amsterdamharu/cf93d154958207b4f938ec58e45ffbde) that reproduces the error you are getting?

You also don't need to bind the handler if you use arrow functions. For example:

```
_navigateToLogin = () => {//arrow function is automatically bound to this
  console.log('in navigate login');
};
```

and

```
<UserForm onCancel={this._navigateToLogin} />
```

Comment: TypeError: this.props.onCancel is not a function
UserForm._cancelForm
D:/Users/.../movies-electronreact-app/src/components/UserForm.jsx:66
  63 |  }
  64 | 
  65 |  _cancelForm() {
> 66 |    this.props.onCancel();
     | ^  67 |  }
  68 | 
  69 |  render () {


This is the error message, that happens when I click the back button on the user form, I also tried with arrow function and it didn't work. Also, I changed the function onCnacel name and no changes

Comment: @LeónDiego I copy and pasted the **code you provided in your question** showing that it works. If you have that error then that's fine but your question does not show code that will produce that error (try code I posted). Maybe you can provide a [snippet](https://gist.github.com/amsterdamharu/cf93d154958207b4f938ec58e45ffbde) that will produce that error because code provided in your question doesn't

Comment: I don't know If this error happens because I'm using material-UI

Comment: @LeónDiego It shouldn't because Button has onClick same as React button (lower case). You can try and replace Button with button but it's probably something else

Comment: The coda that I provide is the one that produces the error, let me try to post the snippet

Comment: My snippet is working correctly but in my code, it doesn't work

Comment: I have found the error, it was on my App.js where I compile everything, the mistake was that I calling the UserForm instead the UserCreate

Comment: @LeónDiego That can happen, you were rendering the wrong component in App and not passing `onCancel ` in props.